# Can't printscreen at all when Skyrim is active window

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Trying to take a screenshot in Skyrim because I'm at the Saarthal part of Forbidden Legend, and there's a gate I don't know how to open. I want to post the picture here to show where I'm at. When I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd> it does nothing at all.

Is there a built-in screenshot feature in Skyrim, or some other way of doing this?

Comment: Assuming you are playing through Steam, are you sure you are using the correct key(s)?

Comment: The key set you list is the same key to perform a regular screenshot? most computers I see use the Fn button, these days, and it catches out a lot of people.

Comment: I have tried both fn + prt sc and alt + prt sc. Someone in chat suggested using f12, but this just works on the Steam version (which I have, as it happens, but other users with the same issue may not?) and I'm not sure what location it stores to.

Comment: You tried ctrl+alt+print screen, I assume

Comment: My Skyrim screenshots are being saved in (Steam version):
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim".
Yes, they are scattered in the main folder. Have you looked there?

I'm not sure, but think the non Steam version would save in the installation folder too

Comment: Does F12 work? If so it's fixed your problem.

Comment: It works. Will it work also for non-Steam users? I'd be willing to accept it as an answer either way, but one that works for non-Steam would be better. (I'm past the bit I was on now anyway :) )

Comment: @fredley User Private Pansy suggested it. It wasn't my answer so I would feel uncomfortable with my name next to it, but if no-one else answers I'll put it down just to help casual browsers.

Comment: @Znes I would also be happy to accept you proposing an answer, since your comment was the final step to solving the problem I had.

Comment: I don't think you can play Skyrim without steam, even if you buy a disc at your local game store, it will still require Steam, so the answer will always be helpful to any Skyrim player that is on PC

Comment: @Vahx I'll wait 24 hours to see if Znes or Private Pansy answer then, and answer myself if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skyrim has a standard screenshot function which you activate by pressing the Print Screen button, screenshots made like this will be placed in the Skyrim installation folder.

If you're playing through Steam you can create screenshots by pressing F12.

Comment: Oh yeah; without the alt/ctrl it works. Where does Print Screen save to in Skyrim?

Comment: In the Skyrim installation folder, which is by default: (C:/Steam/steamapps/common/Skyrim)

Comment: In the root install directory, or in a sub-folder?

Comment: They get placed in the Skyrim folder, which is the highest.

Comment: Root directory is it.

Comment: Yes, it's the root directory